# Can't use format "yyy-dd-mm HH:MM:ss" in jQuery DatePicker to Save MySQL DateTime Field

Tags: javascript, php, html, datepicker

I would like to change the date format from date picker selected date

How do I change this date format

```
DTSTART: 09/18/2020 
DTEND: 09/18/2020
```

To this date forma

```
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T035959Z
```

I tried this , but I am not getting what I want

```
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yyy-dd-mm HH:MM:ss'
   });
```

NOTE: this date will be used in ics file fo calendar in php.

What do I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Hey, no rush, just curious if you could let me know if my answer helped at all.

Comment: hii bro nope didnt

Comment: Hey, The Dead Man, how did it not help?  You're trying to use a datepicker on a datetime field, which I explain can't work.  Besides, could you please explain?  I posted a 100% working demo online: [100% Working Demo for Datepicker](https://jsbin.com/zoqopexeci/edit?html,js,output), as well as [Official jQuery UI Documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) saying to use it as I describe.  Can you explain what's not working?  I mean, just look at your format?  You have Year listed as "YYY", three Y's?  Not sure how my answer didn't help in your multiple problems.

Answer (score -1):

Well, datepicker can only handle *dates*, and you're giving it a format argument containing `HH:MM:ss`.  It won't be able to set your *times*, in that case, you'd want a *time*-picker.

Set your format to: `yy-mm-dd`.  This represents a 4 digit year, 2 digit month, and 2 digit day.

> yy - year (four digit)
>
> mm - month of year (two digit)
>
> dd - day of month (two digit)

Source: **[Official jQuery UI Datepicker Documentation.](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)**

Basically, you just need the format of `'yy-mm-dd'` to be properly insertable date values for MySQL...

```
    $(selector).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            yearRange: '-100:+2',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
    });
```

**[Full, Working Online Demo.](https://jsbin.com/zoqopexeci/edit?html,js,output)**

Results that you can look at:

[image: Example of code with working results]

In addition, as you can see above, this goes from today minus 100 years to today plus 2 years.  If you want to display dates for 1970 to 2025, for instance, the `yearRange` would be `-50:+5`.

Comment: *"you just need the format of 'yy-mm-dd' to be properly insertable date values for MySQL"* - About that; mysql stores as `YYYY`etc.... not 2 of them (Y's).

Comment: Hey, Funk Forty Niner.  Actually, each `Y` represents 2 digits.  Try selecting a date here: [*Working Demo With My Code*](https://jsbin.com/zoqopexeci/edit?html,js,output)  I took the liberty of making a demo with your format: [*Non-Working Demo With Your Format*](https://jsbin.com/ragehojava/edit?html,js,output) -- Output: `20202020-09-08`.

Comment: Notice the [Official jQuery Datepicker Docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/): `yy - year (four digit)`, in fact, "yyyyy" doesn't even appear as an option for dateFormat.